# Removing particular element from list when list is present in a cell of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list

My dataframe consists of lists in each cell and i want to remove a particular value from all these lists without using for loop on the whole dataframe,

```
    TIN        PIN       column       ......

0  [1,2,val]  [0,1]      [val, t, z]  ......
1  [2,val,4]  [14,val]   [b, a, val]  ......
........
```

These val are in string format and i want to remove all of these they exist in some of these lists and doesn't exist in others...

I tried using

`.apply(lambda x: x.remove('nan'|'NaT')` as the val is either nan or NaT in string format,i.e, 'nan' or 'NaT' instead of being null values.....

It gave me an error saying, besides i think my logic itself was wrong there as i think it was trying to remove x instead of what was specified......

Comment: You can't (efficiently) perform this task without a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need, I use the dataframe method `applymap` to apply the lambda function for all cells in the dataframe and the Python `filter` function to remove the unwanted elements in the variable `nan_set`.

```
nan_set = {'val'}
print(
    df.applymap(lambda arr: list(
        filter(lambda element: element not in nan_set, arr)))
)
```

Input:

```
    TIN        PIN          COL
0  [1, 2, val]     [0, 1]  [val, t, z]
1  [2, val, 4]  [14, val]  [b, a, val]
```

Output:

```
    TIN     PIN     COL
0  [1, 2]  [0, 1]  [t, z]
1  [2, 4]    [14]  [b, a]
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine

Comment: Thanks. With more than 50 reputations, now I am able to comment :)).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) the way you were intending, as it returns `None` if the value was found, and raises `ValueError` if it wasn't. One way to do what you want would be to use a nested apply:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'TIN': {0: [1,2,'val'], 1: [2,'val',4]},
     'PIN': {0: [0,1], 1: [14,'val']},
     'column': {0: ['val', 't', 'z'], 1: ['b', 'a', 'val']}}
)
df = df.apply(lambda x:x.apply(lambda y:[v for v in y if v != 'val']))
```

Output:

```
      TIN     PIN  column
0  [1, 2]  [0, 1]  [t, z]
1  [2, 4]    [14]  [b, a]
```

Note performance-wise it's better to use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) (about 35% faster) as described in @LuanNguyen's answer:

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda y:[v for v in y if v != 'val'])
```

Or using a set of values to remove:

```py
remove = { 'val', 'xyz' }
df = df.applymap(lambda y:[v for v in y if v not in remove])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the apply with a custom function.

(you can do most of the code in one line, but it is difficult to understand):

```
Value2Remove='val'

def RemoveVal(Ls,Val):
   if Val in Ls:
       Ls.remove(Val)
   return Ls


df['TIN'] = df['TIN'].apply(lambda x: RemoveVal(x,Value2Remove))
df['PIN'] = df['PIN'].apply(lambda x: RemoveVal(x,Value2Remove))
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: RemoveVal(x,Value2Remove))
```

**Input**:

```
    TIN PIN column
0   [1, 2, val] [0, 1]  [val, t, z]
1   [2, val, 4] [14, val]   [b, a, val]
```

**Output**:

```
    TIN PIN column
0   [1, 2]  [0, 1]  [t, z]
1   [2, 4]  [14]    [b, a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can likely do this with 2 embedded "for" loops, once to iterate across cells in the df, and another to iterate through the list elements in the cell.

```
for cell in df["col"]:
    for listitem in cell:
        if listitem < 10:
            list.pop(n)
        else:
            continue
```

"cell" iterates the df cells, and listitems iterated the elements of the list within the cell. With n meaning the "nth" element in the list. IOW if n = 3 then it will delete the 4TH element of the list (remember 0 is technically the first element).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` by treating each row as a series

```py
def remove_nan(s):
    cols = ['TIN', 'PIN', 'column']
    for col in cols:
            try:
                    s[col].remove('nan')
            except ValueError:
                    pass
    return s
```

Apply this to `df`, set axis to `1` so operation is performed over columns

```py
df_text = df.apply(remove_nan, axis=1)

print(df_text)
```

```json
      TIN     PIN  column
0  [1, 2]  [0, 1]  [t, z]
1  [2, 4]    [14]  [b, a]
```